# Excel cell reference in another cell

Tags: excel, dde

How do I connect two cells to get output (in B1) like below:

```
=Codesys|'C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\ifm_prog.pro'!'Storage.MatrixAngleX[~~numberFromA1~~]'
```

what I mean is that in cell A1 I have function:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>$O$1; ""; ROW(A1))
```

which let's assume is returning `1`

In cell B1 I want to reference output from this cell so the final formula would be something like this:

```
=Codesys|'C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\ifm_prog.pro'!'Storage.MatrixAngleX[1]'
```

Comment: Not possible with Excel Formula yet. You can either link all of the `Storage.MatrixAngleX` ranges and use formula on that, or query the data with Power Query, Microsoft Query, or VBA macro

Comment: Hmm... so is there a way to assign whole array `Storage.MatrixAngleX` to many cells? Assuming it's lenght is 50 , something like this: 'B1:B51 = Storage.MatrixAngleX`. I don't really know excel syntax and it's really grinding my gears :\. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have no idea what `.pro` file and `Storage.MatrixAngleX` is, but usually you can open the source file, copy the range, and then in Excel you can select Paste Link in the Paste Special dialog.

Comment: `.pro` is Codesys project file and `Storage.MatrixAngleX` is an array read over time by PLC from iclinometer. It's university project and my task is to acquire, process and store data from multiple mobile sensors. I'm storing those values in arrays inside PLC memory and I need to export them to Excel. I will take a look at your clues tommorow. Thanks again for your help.